# Regular Expression allow and forbid specific characters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a `RegularExpression` as follows:

```
RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-]*$", ...
```

Is there any way to make it forbid double spaces, double dashes and dash-space/space-dash sequences? Also I need to check if the last character is alphanumeric or not.

`text` OK

`text-text` OK

`text text` OK

`text--text` NOT OK

`text  text` NOT OK

`text- text` NOT OK

`text -text` NOT OK

`text` NOT OK

`-text` NOT OK

`text-` NOT OK

`text` NOT OK

Thank you all I appreciate any tip.

Comment: To check if the last character is alphanumeric or not, you can do: `char.IsLetterOrDigit(str.Last())` or `char.IsLetterOrDigit(str, str.Length-1)`.

Comment: On second thought, why do want to know that? The regex as proposed by @Wiktor Stribiżew's answer only accepts a character in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b+-%5d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%2b%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=%60+OK%0d%0atext%0d%0atext-text%0d%0atext+text%0d%0a%60+NOT+OK%0d%0atext--text%0d%0atext++text%0d%0atext-+text%0d%0atext+-text%0d%0a+text%0d%0a-text%0d%0atext-%0d%0atext+&o=m)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?:[ -][a-zA-Z]+)?` - one or zero sequences of:

  - `[ -]` - a space or `-`
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE:

- If you just need to match any Unicode letter, replace the `[a-zA-Z]` in my pattern with `\p{L}`.
- To check if a string is valid in C#, use `var valid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\p{L}+(?:[ -]\p{L}+)?$");`.

So, based on what you posted, you may use

```
^\p{L}+(?:[ -]\p{L}+)?$
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%20-%5D%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=%60%20OK%0D%0Atext%0D%0Atext-text%0D%0Atext%20text%0D%0A%60%20NOT%20OK%0D%0Atext--text%0D%0Atext%20%20text%0D%0Atext-%20text%0D%0Atext%20-text%0D%0A%20text%0D%0A-text%0D%0Atext-%0D%0Atext%20&o=m)

Comment: Thanks again sir your answer is exactly what I needed.